# How to emit dataChanged in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

The code below breaks on self.emit line. It works fine in PyQt4. How to fix this code so it works in PyQt5?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal

class ItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtWidgets.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index): 
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), index, index)
```

## Edited later:

A working solution:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal

class Communicate(QObject):
    data_changed = pyqtSignal(QtCore.QModelIndex, QtCore.QModelIndex)

class ItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtWidgets.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
        self.c = Communicate()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        self.c.data_changed.emit(index, index)
```

Comment: The `pyqtSlot` decorator should also be given type arguments to reflect the arguments to `setModelData`. Older versions of PyQt5 will make the connection regardless, but PyQt 5.6 [now enforces this](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html#pyqt-v5-6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As you can read here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html), `QtCore.SIGNAL` was discontinued after `PyQt4` and is therefore not compatible.

[This page](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html) explains the new-style signals and slots for `PyQt5`. The syntax is:

```
PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal(types[, name[, revision=0[, arguments=[]]]])
```

Your case could be translated to:

```
from PyQt5 import pyqtsignal

data_changed = pyqtsignal(QModelindex,QModelIndex)
```

and to emit your signal:

```
self.data_changed.emit(index, index)
```

Edit: Solution adapted from comments below.

Comment: Getting `TypeError: string or ASCII unicode expected not 'QModelIndex'` on `data_changed = pyqtSignal(index, index, name="dataChanged(QModelindex,QModelIndex)")`

Comment: The type arguments to the `pyqtSignal` constructor should be data types, not individual instances, ie. `data_changed = pyqtSignal(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)`. `index` should be passed when the signal is emitted `self.data_changed.emit(index, index)`

Comment: user3419537: Oops, I'll edit the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This has become much more simple in PyQt5:

```
self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [QtCore.Qt.EditRole])
```

Comment: I was under the impression that this signal was emitted by the framework and the user just subscribed to it. Wasn't aware the user had to generate it!