QPdfSearchModel dataChanged signal not working
I can't seem to connect the dataChanged signal to anything...Shouldn't it be triggered upon running the script?
I tried the following and get no response aside from the search results:
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListView
from PyQt6.QtPdf import QPdfDocument, QPdfSearchModel

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Create a PDF document
document = QPdfDocument(None)
document.load("/mnt/cloud/cases/24-90004/24-90004/12.pdf")

# Create a search model
search_model = QPdfSearchModel(None)
search_model.setDocument(document)

# Connect the dataChanged signal
search_model.dataChanged.connect(lambda: print("Search results updated!"))

search_model.setSearchString("test")

# Create a list view to display results
list_view = QListView()
list_view.setModel(search_model)



list_view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())


You're connecting the signal after setting the search string, at that point the signal has already been emitted.

@musicamante I moved it still not working. Does it not have something to do with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177144/how-to-emit-datachanged-in-pyqt5

@ScottyCov try with countChanged signal

@ScottyCov after rethinking, it wouldn't matter in any way, I believe that with that model you'd never received that signal, why do you need it to begin with? If you just want to know if the results change, connect to countChanged as noted by eyllanesc.

@eyllanesc unfortunately that only seems to be available for PySide6...For PyQt6 it is still under the "TODO" category in the riverbank documentation and is not an option when I try to select it.

@eyllanesc The Reason I need it is that it takes a little while to update the search results sometimes and in the meantime if the user happens to select a search result that is stale or hasn't been updated from a previously selected pdf the whole thing crashes. So I need to prevent a selection until I know it has updated.

datachanged will not be emitted since the value of item is not changed, what is done is to delete all the items and create them again. datachanged is emitted when the object changes its value but as I told you the object is deleted and others are created. Seems a XY problem

@ScottyCov What do you mean by "is not an option when I try to select it"? That "TODO" is just about the contents of the documentation, it the signal wasn't available it wouldn't be there to begin with. When setSearchString() is called it always resets the current model, so if you still see previous results there's something wrong (probably with your code); there may be issues in case you load a different PDF with similar contents, but we need to know more about your specific issue, because it seems that you're trying to fix the wrong problem. Please provide a more appropriate [mre].
